# Restarting tsserver when node_modules changes, ie; when using npm link

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, node-modules, npm-link, tsserver

When working on an `npm` package it's convenient to use `npm link` for local development.

#### Preamble

For example, assuming the following folder structure:

```
/lib
/consumer
```

An `npm` package "lib" would be in `/lib`, and `npm link .` makes it available for linking. Then, from `/consumer`, running `npm link lib` installs the in-development `lib` package. In `/lib` I'd then run a `build:watch` command to continually rebuild/transpile the library into `js` + `.d.ts` files, and from `/consumer` I'd be using a Hot-Module-Reloading system such as Vite.

During development I would continually switch back and forth between `/lib` and `/consumer`. This works great. I can make changes in either place and the HMR system refreshes the web-app.

However, whenever I make changes in `/lib` this throws the TypeScript server in VSCode. I'll get warnings that the exports for the imported, linked-module are no longer available, and red-underlines abound.

#### Question

Running *"TypeScript: Restart TS server"* from the command-palette fixes the problem every time, so I guess my question is: How can I get the TS server to restart itself automatically in a situation like this? I'm assuming it just needs to know when `node_modules` changes because of the updated linked-library?

Comment: I'm afraid not @aks94 . I also asked on Reddit a few times, but the questions were marked as "spam" for some reason. I've just asked a third time here: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/10lntem/autorestart_ts_server_when_node_modules_changes/

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! I'm experimenting with monorepos instead of using my shared package as an npm package

Answer (score 3):

When you build the `/lib` directory, files inside `node_modules` get deleted. This means you'll need to restart VS Code's TS server. The good news is VS Code is working on an automatic TS restart feature. You can see more about it in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/187208).

Meanwhile, you can try out [this VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neotan.vscode-auto-restart-typescript-eslint-servers). After installing, just specify the files it should watch. For a setup like mine with turborepo and sub-packages, this pattern worked:

```
**/packages/lib/dist/**/*.{ts}
```